# How to send AuthnRequest without user-agent interaction using HTTP POST?

Tags: java, http-post, adfs2.0, saml-2.0

My question is similiar to [How should I be implementing the HTTP POST Protocol Binding for SAML WebSSO Profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884192/how-should-i-be-implementing-the-http-post-protocol-binding-for-saml-websso-prof), but I don't see exact answer that I needed. This is my case. I already implemented Service Provider for WEB SSO SP-initiated POST redirecting and my IDP is active directory and STS is ADFS2.0. After user log on, I need to send another AuthnRequest to ADFS2.0 without user agent interaction. Is it possible with HTTP POST? Or to send over HTTP POST, user agent interaction must needed. I set isPassive=true. I try to implement using Java.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you could build an authentication request and send it to ADFS2 using any HTTP client (i.e. http://www.innovation.ch/java/HTTPClient/ works for me). But ADFS2 will always reponse you with the Login Form. The problem is that in the request you were missing the cookies that ADFS2 is using for tracking your session (SamlSession cookie).

Hope it helps,

Luis

ps: why do you need to send another authn request?