# AuthnRequest body via POST

Tags: php, saml-2.0, onelogin

After a short code review for [php-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml) maintained by OneLogin, it looks like php-saml does not support HTTP-POST for request being send from SP to IdP when SSO is initialised.

Is that correct or I'm missing something?

If HTTP-POST is not supported for initial request:

- shouldn't we be worrying that IdP might respond with "Error 413: Request Entity too large"?
- what about infosec implications sending request via GET?

A bit more insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In SAML "POST binding", no direct POST request is made from the SP to the IDP (or vice versa). The SP uses the client's browser as a conduit to deliver the SAML message to the IDP (and the same happens when the IDP responds).

Read more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4890761/1163424)

And here's an [example of SP-initiated SSO](http://saml.xml.org/wiki/sp-initiated-single-sign-on-postartifact-bindings)

By looking at php-saml library it looks POST binding is supported.

Regarding the infosec implications - In case you pass sensitive data in your SAML request, you have several things you can do to increase security:

- Encrypt SAML message data (Part of the SAML specifications)
- Use artifact binding (Look Scott T. answer to understand the benefits of using Artifact binding - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13618537/1163424)
- And of course, always use SSL